# Writing current time to SVG document

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to add current time to an SVG file using ECMAScript.
Following is the code I have. Unfortunately it's not working. How do I fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   width="300" height="300">
<text x="0" y="15" fill="red">It is now
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
]]>
</script>
</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: What problem are you running into?

Comment: [You can not use `document.write` in SVG](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3396746/929437)

Answer (score 3):

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/M8YXS/

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">It is now <tspan id="now">(time)</tspan></text>

  <!--
    This script block must either be after the element in the source code
    or else the code below must be wrapped in a callback that is invoked
    only after the DOM is created (e.g. window.onload in a browser)
  -->
  <script>
    // Create whatever string you want
    var dateString = (new Date).toDateString();

    // Set the string content of the Text Node child of the <tspan>
    document.getElementById('now').firstChild.nodeValue = dateString;
  </script>
</svg>
```

Comment: can we use document.getElementById('now').children[0] instead of document.getElementById('now').firstChild to prevent the textnodes

Comment: @rajkamal No, you want the [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/childNodes) collection instead of `children`. (But yes, `childNodes[0]` is the same as `firstChild`.) To see the list of properties and methods available for a `<tspan>` element in JavaScript, view [my ObjJob page](http://objjob.phrogz.net/svg/object/143).